# A Strange Playlist

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

As summer draws to a close and the days are getting shorter, a friend and I decide to go on a road trip. Critical to any good journey is the soundtrack, so I ask my friend for some suggestsions.

He provides the following image with a wry smile. He always was a little... different.

Can you help me figure out the playlist, and what sort of music my friend is really in to?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your friend is really into:

> REMIXES

The grid:

> [image]

The answers:

> No More Tears - Ozzy Ozbourne
>  Bullet with Butterfly Wings - Smashing Pumpkins
>  Elderly Woman Behind the Counter in a Small Town - Pearl Jam
>  Lose Yourself - Eminem
>  Radioactive - Imagine Dragons
>  Chlorine - 21 Pilots
>  Bulls on Parade - Rage Against the Machine

Comment: Nicely done! Nailed all of them.